# Two different methods with same RestEndPoint: How will it get resolved?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-restcontroller

I want to know if same `RestEndPoint` which is mapped to two different methods in a controller  be invoked depending upon what each method `PRODUCES`.

The below depicts what I am asking for?

```
@Controller
ContollerClass {

   @GetMapping(value = "/v1/v2/{userID}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getUser( {

      // Rest of code

   }

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/v2/{userID}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getBinUser( {

      // Rest of code

   }
}
```

As seen, it has two different methods for `GET` request and exactly the same `Rest end point`. The only difference is the `return type`  which they return.

Now, when any http client invokes this rest endpoint (can be a `browser`, `curl`, `postman` etc.), how will it distinguish which one would be actually invoked? Does it have anything to do with the `produces` ? And if so, what is that which a client has to invoke the request?  Does it need to provide `accept` HTTP header?

Comment: You can specify this with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` and `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @gnanajeyam95: content-type is the response from server, don't think it has anything to do in how  call would get resolved.

Comment: yeah you can specify this content-type in your request header.

Comment: The also return the same thing. Why should it be 2 different endpoints? Spring will return the correct response based on the accept headers. You shouldn't have multiple endpoints doing the same.